# Strange behavior with form

Tags: atk4

I'm using version 4.1.3

I have a table migrated from access that has a lot of fileds (about 20).

I have a grid and each row has a button "edit" that is an expander and opens a page with a form.

That form uses setConditionFromGet

Some times when I edit a record and go to the next record, if it has some empty fields, those fields are completed with the information of the last record edited.

I don't know if there is some method to clean the form fields before charge them with the data.

Thanks
Alejandro

Comment: I recently disable mod_that was active on the server, I don't know if it helps, but now I'm checking that...

Comment: this might be a browser issue. Do you see it across all browsers? Also, when you reloading grid after edit, do you drop the "ID" argument?

Comment: Hi Romans, I do a stickyForget of the ID. the strange part is that using date files of type varchar works good. It gives me the error using DatePicker and Date in the feld definition. Its an Excel imported worksheet, i don't have this issue when I make it from zero I mean create the table by hand and adding some values. Really strange but I've found that solution, so I think it's ok by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest developers to stay away from setConditionFromGet function. It's removed in 4.2 and it's best to have Grid rely on Model or either specify data manually through setStaticSource();